# Vaadin get focused element

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a problem with focus on Vaadin. The problem occurs when I open new Window (dialog) on e.g. button click:

```
new Window(caption, component);
```

When Window is closed the method close() is executed. Its implementation from Window class:

```
public void close() {
    UI uI = getUI();

    // Don't do anything if not attached to a UI
    if (uI != null) {
        // focus is restored to the parent window
        uI.focus();
        // window is removed from the UI
        uI.removeWindow(this);
    }
}
```

As shown, the focus is set to the UI instead of component which caused a window opened. Is there a way to set component focus to e.g. button which caused window opened? I am looking for a generic solution. I have a workaround in which I am extending Window class and create field for Component. After window is created I set component field to the one which caused the window opened. But as I said - I see it as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any generic way to handle focus with server side code. I have been using 2 approaches for controlling focus after closing window:

1. Keep Focusable as field in class extending Window and focus on close
2. Use close listener and focus next component there

Approach 2 can be extend for more comple cases as well. For example, confirmation dialogs might have listener to handle yes and no answer and you might want to focus different component depending on answer.

In order to keep shortcut listeners working then it is good to have focus at least in UI object.

You should also be aware of Vaadin bug [#5891](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/5891) which might mess with setting focus on window close.

Comment: I implemented it the same way as you described in 1st point. But it is unfortunately no generic and requires a lot of changes in component which are using Window.